# Wordpress/Woo prevent plugin from loading one of its files

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to prevent a Wordpress/Woocommerce plugin from loading one of its files?

For example, in the folder 'woocommerce', I want to disable '/woocommerce/file.php'.

The reason being that the file contains template overides, and if removed I can overide in my theme instead.

Can't find anything online about this.

Comment: How is it overriding a template? Is it a hook or a filter?

Comment: It's a woocommerce template, so can be overidden by placing in /woocommerce/file.php, which exists in the plugin. I can overide in my theme by placing /woocommerce/file.php in my theme, but simply deleting the file in the plugin isnt very future proof with updates etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is then? As you stated, you can override that file by putting your version in your theme. Why don't you do that? You might want to tag this with Woocommerce as well, since that is important information - and Woocommerce is probably one of the best developed plugins in terms of customization.

Comment: I can put the template in my theme, but it only works if the corresponding file in the plugin is deleted, hence not very 'update proof'

Comment: Something might be broken then. WC *should* see your template file and not load it's own.

Comment: The hierarchy goes like this: Plugin, Theme, Woocommerce. I want to change it to Theme, Plugin, Woocommerce.

Comment: First read [WooCommerce template overrides via the theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), **as it don't require to remove the overridden files** from the woocommerce plugin… The problem is somewhere else: You should check and and remove in your `wp-config.php` file for  `define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', true );` that disable the template override feature of WordPress. Or the overriden templates are not in the correct  directory hierarchy in your active theme.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec - the problem is that the plugin version of the template is being used instead of the one in my theme. Is there a way to adjust the priority to ensure the theme version is used instead of the plugin?

Comment: Because you are doing something wrong somewhere… The templates overrides, are made to enable automatically the replacement file located in the theme.

Comment: Must be a problem in the plugin

Comment: Or you're putting the template file in the wrong directory in your theme.

Comment: That's not the case. If the plugin version is removed, my template works fine.